# How to capture numbers in specific range with floating point?

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

The question is straight forward. I have some numbers, and I try to match numbers in range from 0 to 110. Let's say we have five numbers:

> 99.9
>
> 108.712718
>
> 110
>
> 110.2
>
> 9

Here I need to match all except fourth.
I tried a lot. Capturing group, positive/negative lookahead and so on. Nothing works for me. It's easy without floating point, but here I struggling so much.

P.S. I' doing it with Python.

Comment: How are these numbers being stored? You could store them in a list, convert the list elements, and then use list comprehension to only keep the numbers that are less than 110. No need for regex. But without seeing what you have tried can't help you anymore than that.

Comment: Why use regex? Why not simply cast it to a float and check that?

Comment: Beside of other text, they're stored in tuples. Like "Cat weight (1, 100), Dog weight (3, 333)" I just a bit simplified it.
I doing it just for practice and learning. :)

Comment: _"I tried a lot"_ Please remember to always include what you have tried. That being said, maybe something like this `(?<!\.)\b(?:110|(?:10\d|\d\d?)(?:\.\d*)?)\b(?!\.\d)`? [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/ah31YG/1).

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I'm upset that OP didn't answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(?<!\.)\b0*(?:(?:\d\d?|10\d)(?:\.\d+)?|110(?:\.0+)?)\b(?!\.\d)
```

- `(?<!\.)` means "not preceded by a dot (`\.`)"
- `\b` is the word boundary
- `0*` means "preceded by zero or more `0`"
- `(\d\d?|10\d)` means "one digit followed by another optional digit (`\d\d?`) **or** `10` followed by any digit"
- then an optional "dot and one or more digits" (`(\.\d+)?`)
- the last two points are in "or" with the simple number `110` with one or more 0 after a dot (`(?:\.0+)?`)
- another word boundary for matching the end of the number
- and finally `(?!\.\d)`, which means "not followed by a dot and a digit"

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Dct57d/2) a demo.

P.S. If you are matching the correspondence of the whole string, negative lookahead and lookbehind are useless.

Comment: How should 110.00 be handled?

Comment: @Mark I've updated the regex using `(?:\.0+)?`, thank you

Comment: Excellent, an edge case never mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Thanks horcrux for your effort. Seems like make 'or' to match bounds is the only way to do it so far. I guess, it would be a bit tedious if number is much larger(not 110 but 900100 or smth), but it's ok for me.

@Mark there is no any real "edge" cases. Since I didn't gave any specific pattern, I don't expect regex to be 100% valid.

Comment: @CallmeWalter You could consider to accept the answer if it was sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be split into three chunks.
1) 110
2) 100-109.9999999...
3) 0-99.9999999...

The pattern: 
`^(?:(?:10[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.[0-9]+)?|110)$`

`^` start of line
`(?:` start non-capturing group
`(?:10[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]?)` Capture 100-109 or 00-99
`(?:\.[0-9]+)?` Captures the decimal point and the numbers after it 0 or 1 times
`|` or
`110` capture 110 literally
`)` end non-capturing group
`$` end of line

Simples. Questions?

edit: as an afterthought if you do not want leading zeroes (e.g. 00, 01, 02, etc) you could slightly change the pattern to something like `^(?:(?:10[0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(?:\.[0-9]+)?|110)$` the change being `[1-9]?[0-9]` instead of `[0-9][0-9]?`

Comment: p.s. if you found this interesting then you should try doing IP addresses. Start here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html